# WPF: Referring GridView inside UserControl from another project

Tags: wpf, vb.net, gridview, user-controls, mainwindow

Just so you know, i am total newbie of WPF.

So, currently, i have created *two project*, which are, the **MyProject** that contain the **MainWindow** and the other one is a Usercontrol project: **MyUserControl** that holds my **UCGridView**.

I have referred MyUControl to MyProject **(MyProject refer MyUControl)**, and then i tried to create the following inside the MainWindow:

```
  Dim uc As New MyUserControl.UCGridView()
```

What i am trying to achieve is to access the **GridView (x:Name="myGridView")** inside UCGridView by using the code. Maybe by using something like this:

```
  uc.myGridView...
```

Is it possible guys? if possible, then i will really appreciate answers from you all. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes it is possible, just try it out.

Comment: If you're new to WPF, then you might as well start off using it correctly and *not* as you are currently doing. We don't generally create UI objects from code... this is *not* WinForms. Please see the [Walkthrough: Getting Started with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to see how things are *really* done in WPF.

Comment: Thank you for the response har07. The thing is it doesn't come out. When i typed 'uc.' the myGridView never show up as one of the option. It just said Identified Expected.

Comment: Thank you for the link Sheridan. Will do.

Comment: you have to use clr-namespace mapping in WPF.